# Can I get a cumulative In and Out counter for SNMP of my CentOS Linux servers from Nagios?

Tags: centos, snmp, network-traffic, nagios

My SNMP monitoring server (Nagios) has a handful of plugin files for network interface monitoring, none of which so far have really helped me, or my parameters are not correct. I am monitoring remote CentOS (versions 6 & 7) servers in other datacenters. These datacenters charge per month for the total in/out traffic of each server.

I am looking for an end result where I show the cumulative of the in and out counters. Basically, imagine looking at a line graph and the line would basically just keep going up.

To get more advanced, I would like it to reset monthly and start over. Difficulties come into play here because I know these counters can reset if the remote server is rebooted.

A utility such as 'nload' shows me the Total. Is there such a plugin or SNMP script anyone may be aware of that can pull this information, or a quick way to get me started in writing one?

I appreciate any and all assistance.